# If an abelian group contains at most $n$ elements of order divisible by $n$, is it cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

I usually see this question as "if $G$ has at most $n$ solutions to $x^n=1$, then $G$ is cyclic". But here, we have that if $G$ has at most $n$ elements of orders divisible by $n$, then $G$ is cyclic. I am wondering if the following proof works.
3
Let $G$ be such a group with order $|G| = p_1 ^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_k
^{\alpha_k}$ where each $p_i$ is a distinct prime. Every non-identity
element of any $P_i \in \text{Syl}_{p_i}(G)$ has order divisible by
$p_i$ by Lagrange's theorem, but by hypothesis, there are at most $p_i$
such elements, so $|P_i| \le p_i$. Since $P_i$ is not trivial, this
means $P_i \cong C_{p_i}$. Furthermore, $P_i$ is normal because $G$ is
abelian. Because this holds for all $i$, we see that $\alpha_i = 1$ and
$$
  G \cong C_{p_1} \times \cdots \times C_{p_k} \cong C_{p_1 p_2 \cdots
    p_k} \cong C_{|G|}.
  $$

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't think that is true. In $C_4 = \langle x \rangle$ the generator has order $4$ which is divisible by $2$ yet $x^2 \neq 1$.

Comment: @AnneBauval I mentioned something like that question in my first sentence. The lemma in the first answer says that $G$ will be cyclic if the number of elements with order dividing $d$ is less than $d$. My question concerns the same statement but switching "dividing" for "divisible by".

Comment: Yes, I misread. Then, "Yes you are right".

Comment: This looks like there are a few "for all n", probably with some restrictions, missing

Comment: You can even prove that $k=1,$ i.e. $|G|$ is prime.